# pkill -u root lose connection with SSH

Tags: linux, ssh

So I had two additional people access my server via SSH with my root@IP account. There were active sessions while I was working and I wanted to terminate those sessions so no files can be edited.

I ran the command `pkill -u root` and it logged me out of SSH and I can not get back in. The website I was working on is also now not available, server Error code 521.

I want to continue using root account but unable to login. How do I revert this change as I thought the command would only signout all root users, but it looks to have destroyed it instead.

Comment: Sounds like you need to reboot the server then see if you can log in. [killing all root processes](https://linux.die.net/man/1/pkill) will stop the server from functioning. Not all processes will respond to a SIGTERM but I suspect that it would kill the sshd process that is listening for new connections